# Storing user search terms

Tags: php, database, mysql, search, store

I have php application like airbnb. I want to store search values each time user search for listings.

my number 1 solution would be storing it in mysql table, but I'm not sure its wise to do, if site has lots of searchs wouldn't it will slow things down.

should I use mysql or something else?

Comment: Do you permanent or just temporary for search box

Comment: Are you sure you even need to be concerned? Many people overestimate what "many" means in terms of database engines. It might just be what you consider "many" is not even close to any real limit for any database.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking MySQL table performance will depend on a few factors, such as table engine (InnoDB, MyISAM, ...) and the amount of updates vs selects.  If mostly selects you'll be surprised how many millions of rows you can throw into a table with modest hardware.

For your specific use-case, one idea comes to mind: de-duplicate your search terms, since the same values will be often used (we assume).

One table creates a mapping for an auto increment bigint to the unique search terms.  This table has the bigint as primary key, and also a unique constraint on the search terms.

The other table tracks each specific use of the search terms.  This table would have a bigint foreign key to the first table.  Note that this table might end-up being fixed size rows, which can help a bit.

So, you would basically:

1. [`INSERT IGNORE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert.html) into first table (search terms)
2. select from first table to get key
3. insert into second table

Three round-trips per query.

If we knew more about what you mean by search values, we could provide a table model, which might end up with a third table if you need many-to-many relationships.  But I just wanted to present the idea of de-duplicating data that may be redundant.

Also, don't underestimate the importance of small row size in MySQL for tables accessed frequently.  It doesn't have anything like PostgreSQL's [TOAST](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/storage-toast.html), as far as I know.  So pulling out less frequently updated or access values that have long content into a separate one-to-one or one-to-many table can be a big win.

Answer (score 0):

If your concern is lots of searches my first inclination is to simply make sure you store this unrestricted growth in a separate volume than the running application.  You can do that as a log file or a separate DB from the main one.

Of Course there are more elegant ways to constrain growth (rolling log files etc) but I like to consider the brutally simple first.